# is there any other way to get data from database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, random

I have a table on mysql and I want to show one of the fields, its the `id` field and I want to show it on my email layout on Laravel. the `id` field consist on some random code generated by the `rand()` function.

and I've tried it this way:

```
{{ $data->id }}
```

but, the returned value on the email view is `0`.

// This is what I wrote on the email view

```
<td align="left" class="esd-block-text es-p15t es-p10b">                                                                                  
<p style="font-size: 16px; color: #777777;">Thank you for filling in the lost items form. Here are some details from your report .<br></p>
<p style="font-size: 16px; color: #777777;">first your report ticket number is  {{ $data->id }} <br></p>
<p style="font-size: 16px; color: #777777;"><br></p>
<p style="font-size: 16px; color: #777777;">Your details:<br></p>
<table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
```

I expect the output to be the `id` from the `id` field on database. But it turns out to be `0`.

Any idea why?

## Edit

this is the controller:

```
$data = Dekripsi::create([
            'id'=>mt_rand(),
            'date' => Carbon::parse(request('date')),
            'location' => request('location'),
            'locationdetails' => request('locationdetails'),
            'flightnumber' => request('flightnumber'),
            'origin' => request('origin'),
            'destination' => request('destination'),
            'typeproperty' => request('typeofproperty'),
            'other' => request('other'),
            'itemimage' => $nama,
            'name' => request('name'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'phone' => request('phone'),
        ]);
```

Comment: where did `$data->id` come from? i'm assuming this came from a controller somewhere, you should include it on the question too

Comment: $data is coming from the controller, but the $data->id is the way i use to pass the data to my email blade template. I'm so sorry Im afraid I do not  understand your question :(

Comment: you did understood my question, if `{{ $data->id }}` did come from your controller, then you should check that code responsible for setting `$data`. your view file just `echo` the value, there's not much to go on after that. the value setting is in the controller. you should add the controller codes too

Comment: You're setting the id to random number, is your model applying the same way? did you set this 2 `protected $primaryKey = 'your_key_name'; | public $incrementing = false;`

Comment: i did not set my model like that :/

Comment: IT WORKS!! thank you so much :)

Comment: Set Your Model first .

I notice you are using mt_rand() function for id But take care about some problems can occur

1- the id value can repeat

2- value can be 0 as manual say

3- if the value from the function more than the column length the model will ignore it and put 0 instead .

Some solutions

check the table before insert the value of id to avoid repeat problem

make sure the return value of return function mt_rand() is not zero

finally check the length of the return value function mt_rand()

Comment: for what reason you are generating random id like that

Comment: @sssS its a school project which I have to make  a website for lost and found service this website also has filter to generate daily report  so i use mt_rand() to generate those numbers to identify every submitted lost/found case to the website. I'm sorry I'm bad at explaining hehe

Comment: @ellvina  ok ,all the best for your project carry on